# Browsing a collection of photos from a directory?

Tags: android, android-image, android-file

I am wondering if there is a built-in feature that does this or if I need to home-roll my own view or use an external library, but let's say I have a designated folder (could be either in internal storage or public/private external storage) and I want to be able to allow the user to view any pictures they have in this folder, select any number of them arbitrarily, delete them if desired, run custom code if a picture is clicked, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to design that on your own. There's no in-built file explorer/file manager provided by android APIs.

Comment: So something like RecyclerView (for allowing LinearLayouts and GridLayouts), storing an array designating selected photos and then changing some small image overlay (i.e. like a checkbox) on top of each photo to indicate selection... is this how people do it?

Comment: Yes kind of. There are multiple ways to do it. Also, there are multiple open source libraries available. You can check this [List](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35).